# Android: Variable has two states

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Sorry for the uninformative title, didn't realy know how to describe my problem in a short way. I tried so solve it since 3 hours and I have no idea, what to google for or what else to try.

I have a Recyclerview with views, that intercept the back press event via `onKeyPreIme()`. This is the View:

```
public class TestView extends LinearLayout {

    int a = 1;

    public TestView(Context context, AttributeSet att) {
        super(context, att);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout, this, true);



        findViewById(R.id.setBtn).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                a = 2;
            }
        });

        findViewById(R.id.readBtn).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i("LOG", "value of a: " + a);
            }
        });

        this.setFocusable(true);
        this.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        this.requestFocus();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        Log.i("LOG", "value of a: " + a);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now in the beginning `a = 1`. After setBtn is clicked it's 2, which is confirmed when pressing `readBtn`. But when I press the back button, the value of *a* is printed as 1! If I press the `readBtn` afterwards, the value of *a* is printed as 2. This only happens on the first two views. For the following ones (those that were probably not created but reused), the behaviour is correct.

Comment: By using above code I'm getting 2 if set is clicked and 1 if  it is not clicked.

Comment: Did you try it in a recyclerview? If I use the directly, everything works as expected.